# SQL Server - Cross join with where / on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a table with monthly data for employees that I'd like to do cross joins but only after making sure they're in the same month.  Table looks like this:

```
  Month      Emp_id
1/1/2017      123
1/1/2017      234
1/1/2017      345
1/1/2017      456
2/1/2017      123
2/1/2017      234
2/1/2017      345
  ...
```

I'd like to do something like this:

```
select *
from t1
cross join t1 as t2
   on t1.Month = t2.Month
```

Is there a way to do this?

EDIT:

To elaborate,  if I have 100 employees in each month and 12 months I'm looking to get an output table with 120,000 rows (100 * 100 Cartesian for each month, times 12 (1 for each month) instead of doing a full Cartesian which would be 1,440,000.

Comment: You mean an `INNER JOIN`? A `CROSS JOIN` is used to create a cartesian product, you don't use an `ON` clause with it. *Edit: you could use a `WHERE` clause, however then the `CROSS JOIN` implicitly becomes an `INNER JOIN`, and then using the correct syntax would be better.*

Comment: @Larnu - yes - is there a way to create a cartesian but only within a given month?

Comment: I don't actually understand what you mean. Sorry. You might want to try to elaborate more in your question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, it is called an `inner join`:

```
select *
from t1 inner join
     t1 t2
     on t1.Month = t2.Month
```

You could express the same thing using `where` and `cross join`, but I think an `inner join` is better than:

```
select *
from t1 cross join
     t1 t2
where t1.Month = t2.Month;
```

Note that you are using `select *`, which means that you will have duplicate column names and not know which `t1` they are coming from.  If that is an issue, ask another question.

Comment: Will inner join give me cartesian within each month?

Comment: @screechOwl - An `INNER JOIN` takes every row in the left hand table *(`t1`)* and matches it against every row in the right hand table *(`t2`)* where the join predicate *(`t1.Month = t2.Month`)* evaluates to `TRUE`.  I strongly recommend simply going through a basic SQL Tutorial which will elaborate on the for you.